# Passing list of custom data type from Haskell to C++

Tags: c++, haskell, custom-data-type

I'm using Haskell functions into a C++ program with `foreign export ccall`.

It is easy to pass basic types from one language to another, but how can I pass more complexe types like this one:

```
piecesList::[Piece]
piecesList = [Piece _type _color _coords, ..., ... Piece _type _color _coords]
```

with :

```
data Piece = Piece {
  _type :: PieceType,
  _color :: PieceColor,
  _position :: Position
} deriving Eq

data PieceColor = Black | White deriving Eq
data PieceType = Rook | Knight | Bishop | King | Queen | Pawn deriving Eq
type Position = (Int, Int)
```

If I do (for example):

```
get_piecesList::[Piece]
get_piecesList = piecesList
```

and

```
foreign export ccall get_piecesList :: [Piece]
```

I got:

```
 Unacceptable result type in foreign declaration:
    ‘[Piece]’ cannot be marshalled in a foreign call
• When checking declaration:
    foreign export ccall "get_piecesList" get_piecesList :: [Piece]
```

How can I pass this kind of data, and how can I handle it in c++?

Thank you

Comment: I suppose you also have already a C++ class `Piece` that you'd like to map this to? And you store it as `std::vector<Piece>`, or what? That, too, are things that should be included in the question...

Comment: See https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface#Marshalling_data.  You should also probably look around for tools to help out since it's kind of a pain.

Comment: Ok, looks a pain indeed... I'm going to do it in another way. Thanks